# MySQL Select where count

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT l.user_id, u.ID, u.ULN, count(u.ULN) As ULN_count
FROM table_Learning l
LEFT JOIN table_users u 
ON l.ULN = u.ULN
WHERE l.user_id is null
AND (SELECT COUNT(ULN) 
    FROM Table_users 
    WHERE ULN = u.ULN 
    GROUP BY ULN) < 2
GROUP BY u.ULN
```

What I would expect from this query is that The value of the field `ULN_Count` cannot be greater than 1.

However, the query does not achieve this as the filed has values greater than 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show some sample data from the two involved tables. It is possible  you are running afoul of MySQL's lenient `GROUP BY` behavior because you have several columns in `SELECT` not also included in `GROUP BY` and not aggregated. That will often cause indeterminate groupings, and results in a compile error in most RDBMS besides MySQL.

Comment: But looking at the structure of your subselect in `WHERE`, it seems like that entire thing may be eliminated from `WHERE` and replaced with `HAVING COUNT(u.ULN) < 2`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski if you put that as an answer I will mark it as correct

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes but you answered it so i am not marking the one below as correct

Comment: okay then, I'll add one with a thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subselect in the `WHERE` clause is making comparisons on the aggregate `COUNT(u.ULN)` value, and therefore really belongs in a `HAVING` clause. It should be significantly more performant there, because the subselect would be evaluated for every row returned by the outer query while the `HAVING` filter will only be applied once for the entire aggregate query.

```
SELECT
  l.user_id,
  u.ID, u.ULN,
  count(u.ULN) As ULN_count
FROM
  table_Learning l
  LEFT JOIN table_users u 
    ON l.ULN = u.ULN
WHERE l.user_id is null
GROUP BY u.ULN
-- The aggregate can be compared & filtered in HAVING
-- which is applied just once for the whole query
-- and you can use the alias for comparison
HAVING ULN_count < 2
```

Without seeing your sample data, it is possible that MySQL's default `GROUP BY` behavior may cause you some grief. All columns in the `SELECT` which are not part of an aggregate like `COUNT(),SUM(),MAX()` should also be included in the `GROUP BY`, in particular if you are joining multiple tables. In something other than a one-to-one relationship, MySQL may return indeterminate results for the ungrouped columns (`l.user_id` in this context).

Answer (score 1):

You have to move this subquery to having state like this

```
SELECT 
     l.user_id, u.ID, u.ULN, count(u.ULN) As ULN_count
FROM 
    Table_Learning l
    LEFT JOIN table_users u ON l.ULN = u.ULN
WHERE 
     l.user_id is null
GROUP  BY u.ULN
HAVING  count(u.ULN) < 2
```